# Socket Servers Viability

Tags: java, sockets

i have designed a Socket base Server for android clients, which receives requests and deals with mysql database, now im expecting about 2000 requests per hour, im wondering is this server viable for that amount or even more? is there any thing else or any better protocol i should use instead socket to can deal with larger requests, but thre ThreadPoolExecutor?

```
 public class Server {
// a unique ID for each connection
private static int uniqueId;
// an ArrayList to keep the list of the Client
private ArrayList<ClientThread> al;
// if I am in a GUI
private ServerGUI sg;
// to display time
private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
// the port number to listen for connection
private int port;
// the boolean that will be turned of to stop the server
private boolean keepGoing;
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openfire";
static final String USER = "admin";
static final String PASS = "admin";
static boolean jobdone = false;
protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
protected boolean      isStopped    = false;
protected Thread       runningThread= null;


Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;

public Server(int port) {

    this(port, null);
}

public Server(int port, ServerGUI sg) {

    this.sg = sg;

    this.port = port;

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    al = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
}

public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    keepGoing = true;
    try 
    {

        // the socket used by the server
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        // infinite loop to wait for connections
        while(keepGoing) 
        {
            // format message saying we are waiting
            display("Server waiting for Clients on port " + port + 
 ".");

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();      // accept 
  connection
            // if I was asked to stop

            if(!keepGoing)
                break;
            ClientThread t = new ClientThread(socket);  // make a 
  thread of it
            jobdone=false;

 al.add(t);                                 // save 
 it in the ArrayList
            t.start();
        }
        // I was asked to stop
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
            for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                ClientThread tc = al.get(i);
                try {
                tc.sInput.close();
                tc.sOutput.close();
                tc.socket.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ioE) {
                    // not much I can do
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            display("Exception closing the server and clients: " + e);
        }
    }
    // something went bad
    catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = sdf.format(new Date()) + " Exception on new ServerSocket: " + e   
 +  "\n";
        display(msg);
    }
}       
/*
 * For the GUI to stop the server
 */
protected void stop() {
    keepGoing = false;
    // connect to myself as Client to exit statement 
    // Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    try {
        new Socket("localhost", port);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // nothing I can really do
    }
}
/*
 * Display an event (not a message) to the console or the GUI
 */
private void display(String msg) {
    String time = sdf.format(new Date()) + " " + msg;
    if(sg == null)
        System.out.println(time);
    else
        sg.appendEvent(time + "\n");
}

    // create a server object and start it



 public static void shutdown() {
jobdone = true;


 }
/** One instance of this thread will run for each client */

   class ClientThread extends Thread {
    // the socket where to listen/talk
    String Type;
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream sInput;
    ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
    // my unique id (easier for deconnection)
    int id;

    String encrypted = "'adomgaldkopnfaosdppkdsad'";


    // Constructore
    ClientThread(Socket socket) throws InterruptedException {
        // a unique id
        id = ++uniqueId;
        this.socket = socket;
        /* Creating both Data Stream */
        System.out.println("Thread trying to create Object Input/Output 
 Streams");
    while (!jobdone){
        try
        {
            // create output first
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            // read the username


            String RegisterRequest = (String) sInput.readObject();  

            String[] result = RegisterRequest.split("\\,");
            String theuser = result[0];
            display("theuser="+theuser);
            String thepass = result[1];
            display("thepass="+thepass);
            String thename = result[2];   
            display("thename="+thename);
            String themail = result[3];
            display("themail="+themail);
            String thephone = result[4];
            display("thephone="+thephone);
            String newRID = result[5];
            display("RID="+newRID);



            String OldRID=newRID;
            try{
                  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                  //STEP 3: Open a connection
                  System.out.println("Connecting to a selected 
 database...");
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, 
 PASS);
                  System.out.println("Connected database 
 successfully...");

                  String selectSQL1 = "SELECT username FROM ofuser 
 WHERE username= '"+theuser+"'";
                  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
 conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL1);
                  ResultSet usernameRS = 
 preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL1);


                  if (!usernameRS.next()){



                  //STEP 4: Execute a query
                  System.out.println("Inserting records into the  
 table...");
                  stmt = conn.createStatement();

                  String sql = "INSERT INTO ofuser VALUES 

('"+theuser+"','"+thepass+"',null,'"+thename+"','"+themail+"',
'"+4234+"','"+23432+"','"+the
 phone+"','"+null+"','"+null+"')";
                  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                     Type="T"; 
                  String REresponse ="('"+Type+"','"+OldRID+"')";
                  System.out.println(REresponse);
                  sOutput.writeObject(REresponse);
                  sOutput.flush();
                  //  sOutput.writeObject(Type);
                  System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                  }else{ 

                      Type="F";
                    String REresponse ="('"+Type+"','"+OldRID+"')";
                    Type="F";   
                            sOutput.writeObject(REresponse);
                            sOutput.flush();
                            System.out.println("FAIL");
                  }



                  return;




              }catch(SQLException se){
                  //Handle errors for JDBC
                  se.printStackTrace();
               }catch(Exception e){
                  //Handle errors for Class.forName
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }finally{
                  //finally block used to close resources
                  try{
                     if(stmt!=null)
                        conn.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se){
                  }// do nothing
                  try{
                     if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se){
                     se.printStackTrace();
                  }//end finally try
            }
               }//end try






        catch (IOException e) {
            display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + 
 e);
            return;
        }
        // have to catch ClassNotFoundException
        // but I read a String, I am sure it will work
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Server.shutdown();
    }

   }
    // what will run forever

        // remove myself from the arrayList containing the list of the
        // connected Clients
    public void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // start server on port 1500 unless a PortNumber is specified 
        int portNumber = 1500;
        switch(args.length) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid port number.");
                    System.out.println("Usage is: > java 
  Server [portNumber]");
                    return;
                }
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server  
 [portNumber]");
                return;

        }
        // create a server object and start it
        Server server = new Server(portNumber);
        server.start();
    }







    // try to close everything
    private void close() {
        // try to close the connection
        try {


            if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
        try {
            if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {};
        try {
            if(socket != null) socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    /*
     * Write a String to the Client output stream
     */
    private boolean writeMsg(String msg) {
        // if Client is still connected send the message to it
        if(!socket.isConnected()) {
            close();
            return false;
        }
        // write the message to the stream
        try {
            sOutput.writeObject(msg);
        }
        // if an error occurs, do not abort just inform the user
        catch(IOException e) {
            display("Error sending message to " );
            display(e.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
}



//public void main(String[] args) {


    //   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
//  }//end main




 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be aware of high ram usage, it seems you're creating so much objects per request...
my suggestion is that you should create a limited number of objects(for example 100) and then put them into an **ArrayList** and then call them respectively, I mean :

```
public static void startServer() {
    try {
        final ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(12345);
        final List<Operator> operators = new ArrayList<>();
        final int nOperators = /* your choice */;
        for (int i = 0; i < nOperators; i++) {
            operators.add(i, new Operator());
        }
        final int parallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
        pool.submit(() -> new Thread(() -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    operators.get(i).newOperation(serverSocketChannel.accept());
                    i++;
                    if (i == nOperators) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
        })).fork().invoke().start();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
}
```

and then you will see a huge increase in speed and performance...

EDIT:

for example:

```
public class Operator {

    public void newOperation(final SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socketChannel.socket().getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socketChannel.socket().getOutputStream());
        //TODO something here
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
        socketChannel.close();
    }

}
```

more information about **[ServerSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html)** and **[SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)** and **[ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)**

good luck :)

---

EDIT by @PeterLawrey This is how I might write it assuming I has lots of short lived connections with CPU intensive operations.  If you have operations which block on network/IO you might want more threads.  Since you want Plain IO, it makes sense to stick with plain IO.

```
public static void startServer() throws IOException {
    // don't ignore the server failing to bind.
    final ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);

    final int parallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    // add one for the acceptor
    final ExecutorService pool = ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism+1);

     pool.submit(() -> {
         try {
             while (!ss.isClosed())
                 pool.submit(new Handler(serverSocketChannel.accept()));
         } catch (IOException ignored) {
     });
}

class Handler implements Runnable {
   static final ThreadLocal<ExpensiveObject> expensiveObjectIWantToReuse = new ThreadLocal<>();

   final Socket s;
   final DataInputStream in;
   final DataOutputStream out;

   Handler(Socket s) {
      this.s = s;
      this.in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
      this.out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
          processStream(in, out);
      } catch (Throwable t) {
          // log t
      } finally (
          close(out);  // also flush()es
          close(in);
          close(s);
      }
   }

   public static void close(Closable c) {
      try {
          if (c != null) c.close();
      } catch (IOException ignored) { }
   }

   protected void processStream(DataInput di, DataOutput out) {
      // do something
   }
```

}

Comment: thanks, how ever i have no idea what these commands are, but ill look for a tutorial for them :) tnx alot mate

Comment: dude, could you give me some tips about what this code does,where should i use it at, and what is its differencewith normal serversocket, should i replace it?..please?

Comment: Can you explain why you are setting configureBlocking(true) (this is the default), why you are using 64 operators, why does this change the number of objects per request, why you are using the fork-join framework at all, why you are submitting threads instead of Runnables etc.  There is lots of boiler plate code, but none of it seems to add performance , just obscurity.  Why use SocketChannel for NIO and switch back to plain IO unbuffered DataStreams instead of native ByteBuffers

Comment: I'm using something like this in my own server application and I can say it's very very fast and efficient, my server application is now handling over 3000 ~ 3500 connections per second and overal ram usage is just under 60 MB...

Comment: @AvB are you sure you want me to delete anything I don't understand ;)

Comment: @AvB That is good for 60 MB.  This would be more efficient if you kept a connection open for each request.  Creating a new connection is expensive.  HOw many concurrent connections would you have?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Nooo :))))... I'm just controlling number of objects and not creating new objects, just using previously created objects again...

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't know how many concurrent connections I have but one of my reasons for using ForkJoinPool was concurrent connections

Comment: @AvB I have added my edit instead of changing yours.  I have added support for re-using expensive objects.   Note: this uses less closures and Thread objects so you might find this uses less memory.  ForkJoin is built on ExecutorService and appears to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

2000 per hour is ~ 0.55 per second.  You should be able to handle that rate on a mobile phone running as your server (assuming the requests are not complex)

if you need to handle up to 100K connections and over one billion requests per hour, TCP is likely to be fine.  If you want much more than this you could use UDP, or buy a second server. More servers is likely to be much simpler ;)

Note: your database and/or your network bandwidth is likely to be max-ed out long before your TCP server will be.

Comment: yes i understoud, thank you veeeery much, do you need any good guide how can i turn this into TCP?

Comment: @user3764748 I would avoid using Object Streams if you can, otherwise it looks ok to me.

Comment: what do you offer to replace with mate?

Comment: @user3764748 There is too many options to mention here, but if you need just text I would use BufferedReader/PrintWriter.  For data I would use buffered DataInputStream/DataOutputStream

Comment: UDP doesn't magically make things more scalable. It actually tends to be less scalable due to the increased likelihood of network congestion with a lot of connections and data moving around. Hardware also tends to be specialized for optimizing TCP connections more than UDP and can manage the kind of congestion you get with hundreds of thousands of concurrent connections. Using UDP would mean you would have to basically add support for managing packet loss and probably build some lightweight TCP-esque thing anyway; that is asking for trouble with the added complexity. More hardware is easier.